# How to wire @Configuration files from Unit Test - Spring Boot + Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, junit

I have an **application.yml** with some configuration properties required by my application.

```
SF:
 baseurl: https://xxxxx
 case:
   recordTypeId: 0124a0000004Ifb
  application:
   recordTypeId: 0125P000000MkDa
  address:
    personal:
      recordTypeId: 0125P000000MnuO
  business:
    recordTypeId: 0125P000000MnuT
```

I have defined a configuration class to read those properties as follows:

```
@Configuration
class SFProperties(
 @Value("\${sf.case.recordTypeId}") val caseRecordTypeId: String,
 @Value("\${sf.application.recordTypeId}") val applicationRecordTypeId: String,
 @Value("\${sf.address.personal.recordTypeId}") val addressPersonalRecordTypeId:String,
 @Value("\${sf.address.business.recordTypeId}") val addressBusinessRecordTypeId: String
)
```

The class is wired within a service without any issues,

```
@Service
class SFClientManagementServiceImpl( val webClientBuilder: WebClient.Builder): 
ClientManagementService {

....
@Autowired
lateinit var sfProperties: SFProperties
 

 override fun createCase(caseRequest: CaseRequestDto): Mono<CaseResponseDto> {   
    ...
     var myValue= sfProperties.caseRecordTypeId
    ....

   }   

}
```

When trying to test this service, I get a **"lateinit property sfProperties has not been initialized"** exception:

The test looks as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = [SFProperties::class])
class SalesforceClientManagementServiceImplTests {


@Autowired
open lateinit var sfProperties: SFProperties

 @Test
fun `createCase should return case id when case is created`() {


     val clientResponse: ClientResponse = ClientResponse
            .create(HttpStatus.OK)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .body(ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(Fakes().GetFakeCaseResponseDto())).build()
    val shortCircuitingExchangeFunction = ExchangeFunction {
        Mono.just(clientResponse)
    }
    val webClientBuilder: WebClient.Builder = WebClient.builder().exchangeFunction(shortCircuitingExchangeFunction)

    val sfClientManagementServiceImpl =
            SFClientManagementServiceImpl(webClientBuilder)

    var caseResponseDto = 
          salesforceClientManagementServiceImpl.createCase(Fakes().GetFakeCaseRequestDto())

    var response = caseResponseDto.block()

    if (response != null) {
        assertEquals(Fakes().GetFakeCaseResponseDto().id, response.id)
    }
}
```

I have tried many other annotations on the Test class but without success, I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Why are you creating the service instance yourself, instead of auto-wiring it (as you would within the main app)?  Spring does a lot of magic, including constructor params, hidden methods, and hidden subclasses, that need it to be in control.  I strongly suspect (though am not certain, hence posting this as a comment!) that if you autowired it, it'd work.

Comment: Thanks @gidds, Yes basically because that service is using webClient to make a call to an external API. I am mocking that call building  my own webClient and pass it as parameter to the service, so it does not make the remote call. I have updated my service code for u to have a look. So i would need to change the whole approach.?? Any other option to get the sfProperties class wired?